# How do I get IzPack to add program to Program and Features

Tags: java, windows, installation, izpack

I'm using IzPack 5.0 beta 11 to package up my Java application.

How do I get a program installed using IzPack on Windows to appear in Program and Features as an installed program?

**EDIT**
I've found some information about putting things in the registry with Izpack 5 http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/registry but Im still struggling to understand quite what I do the documentation is vague. I simply want my program to be shown in Programs and Features, and it be possible to uninstall from there.

Comment: What is "Program and Features"?  Does the app. have a GUI?

Comment: Part of the Windows 7 Control Panel, whereby you can see what programs are installed and uninstall them. Yes my application does have a gui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found this page http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=142803064, the documentation is a bit outdated for Izpack 5 beta 11 but eventually worked out all I needed to get it working on a 32-bit installtion was add the following to my install.xml

```
<natives>
   <native type="3rdparty" name="COIOSHelper.dll" stage="both">
   </native>
</natives>

<listeners>
    <listener classname="RegistryInstallerListener" stage="install"/>
    <listener classname="RegistryUninstallerListener" stage="uninstall"/>
</listeners>
```

and for 64 bit:

```
<natives>
   <native type="3rdparty" name="COIOSHelper_x64.dll" stage="both">
   </native>
</natives>

<listeners>
    <listener classname="RegistryInstallerListener" stage="install"/>
    <listener classname="RegistryUninstallerListener" stage="uninstall"/>
</listeners>
```

Giving the following advantages:

- I dont get asked if it installed properly after installation.
- It is listed in Program and Features
- It can be uninstalled from Program and Features

Comment: Where do you get those DLLs?  They're not part of the IzPack that I just downloaded.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Natives are located at IZPACK_HOME\bin\native\3rdparty

Comment: I have added these configurations, however it's still not creating an entry in Programs and Features on windows machine. I'm using Izpack version `5.1.3`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative:  Install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS can not only install desktop icons and start menu items for Java apps. on any platform that supports them (I.E. 'not just Windows'), but also puts them in the "Programs and Features" dialog as seen below for "Star Zoom Animation".

[image: Java app. icon and entry in "Programs and Features"]

Comment: Thanks, but I dont think this is suitable, for one thing its too tied to Java, Ive learnt the less I mention java the better as it has a (undeserved) bad reputation on the desktop

Comment: *"its too tied to Java"* And a Jar isn't?  If you mean 'too branded by Java', then use 1) A splash to replace the default splash screen 2) The native PLAF 3) An icon to represent the app.

Comment: I wrap my jar in an exe, so there is very little Java about if from the pov of the user.