# Spring Boot and MongoDB - installable

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

My application is written with Spring Boot and uses MongoDB as DB. Normally I install this application at a server but now I have a request installing it at a client computer.
My question now would be if there is a possiblity to do this in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at how to install a Java application on a desktop.  See this post [Creating an installer for Java desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685149/creating-a-installer-for-java-desktop-application)