# Deploying a Java Desktop application built in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, jar, desktop-application

I am currently Developing a Windows based Java Desktop Application. I am working on Eclipse IDE. I am curious to know how to Deploy my app so that others can also use my app. Also can It run if jre is not present on client's pc. Could anyone give me a detailed Procedure to do so.
I have built the application by using Swing Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, I understand you right, you want to export your application as jar file?
If that so, you can right click on your project and click export. Here you can choose export as jar or as runnable jar-file. I would prefer a runnable jar so you can execute that on every pc.

An another way to do that is to use maven. with maven you can package a runnable jar
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Tutorial%3A+Build+a+JAR+file+with+Maven+in+5+minutes

Comment: So the runnable jar will run without jre on clients pc?

Comment: No, the pc should have an jre

Comment: Can I make a Installer so that I can include the jre files as well?

Comment: Look here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685149/creating-an-installer-for-java-desktop-application